# Is DynamoDB's C# API DescribeTableResponse returning incorrect data?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple DynamoDB table with a Hash Key and an Index

Table:

- Name: bank-statements
- Hash Key: MTSTransactionID of type N
- Index: StatementType-index of type S

When I do this:

```
DescribeTableResponse descResponse = _dynamoDbClient.DescribeTable(new DescribeTableRequest
                {TableName = "bank-statements"});

tableDescription = descResponse.Table;
```

then,

- tableDescription.AttributeDefinitions.Count = 2.  The 2 items are the
  Key and the Index
- tableDescription.KeySchema.Count = 1.  The 1 item
  is the Key

Then I use the tableDescription to recreate the table by doing this:

```
CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest
{
   TableName = tableDescription.TableName,
   AttributeDefinitions = tableDescription.AttributeDefinitions,
   KeySchema = tableDescription.KeySchema,
   ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput
   {
      ReadCapacityUnits = tableDescription.ProvisionedThroughput.ReadCapacityUnits,
      WriteCapacityUnits = tableDescription.ProvisionedThroughput.WriteCapacityUnits
   }
 };

 CreateTableResponse response = _dynamoDbClient.CreateTable(createTableRequest);
```

However, this produces an error:

> One or more parameter values were invalid: Number of attributes in KeySchema does not exactly match number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions

Which is true but means either

- the data being returned is wrong
- The error is incorrect as clearly the table does not need that constraint

What can I do to use the DescribeTableResponse to recreate the table anew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a key that is used by your index but you aren't creating the index. That leaves you with an unused key.

Comment: When I created the table on line I added an Index by specifying the Partition key (StatementType).  AWS then seemed to make an Index called StatementType-index.
The AWS UI Indexes tab tells me I have an Index.

Is there something else I need to do to make the index "Live"?

Comment: The `DescribeTableResponse` includes the property of `GlobalSecondaryIndexes`. If you have an index on your table there will be values there. It's not that the index isn't live, it's that you haven't created it on the new table.

Comment: OK I can see that.
However, slightly surprisingly, I can't add GlobalSecondaryIndexes directly to the createTableRequest from TableDescription.GlobalSecondaryIndexes because  these Types are not the same.

CreateTableRequest.GlobalSecondaryIndexes is List<GlobalSecondaryIndex>
TableDescription.GlobalSecondaryIndexes  is List<GlobalSecondaryIndexDescription>

Comment: It doesn't make sense for them to be the same. The description one includes things like index status and item count. Neither of those are relevant to creating the index.

Comment: Perhaps but it breaks the "convention" used in the other fields of TableDescription and CreateTableRequest whereby fields of the same name use the same type.  Different things really should have different names (GlobalSecondaryIndexes).
It looks like I can "foreach" through GlobalSecondaryIndexDescription to get the data to fill GlobalSecondaryIndex